# What kind of fish is this? I don't remember the full name but it started with Tiger

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

name starts with tiger, forgot the rest, please help

[image]

Comment: Where is it from? Do you know that?

Comment: I got it from a local pet store called Elliot's

Comment: In which country is it?

Comment: Please add some more information about it, like its size, habitat (where you live), etc.

Comment: You could just go to the pet store and ask.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a juvenile tiger loach, or tiger botia.

[image: Wikipedia picture of Tiger Loach]

*Adult Tiger Loach*

[image: Ypunger individual]

*Younger individual of another species*

These fish are from the genus *Syncrossus* and the family *Botiidae* which include many common aquarium fishes. This genus comes from India, Myanmar, and Southern Asia.

These fish can grow up to 20-25cm (~10in).

Syncrossus species can be told appart using appropriate litterature. [This specie sheet from seriously-fish](http://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/syncrossus-berdmorei/) is well documented and provide interesting links from further reading and a quick explanation of its taxonomy easily accessible for the average guy,